# Effect of pressure when drying wet clothes in a windy environment

Tags: pressure, bernoulli-equation, evaporation, convection, heat-conduction

When we hang wet clothes outside, they dry faster if it is windy.

The wind causes forced convection and removes the air saturated with vapor, and the rate of evaporation does not decrease much in time this way. And also the wind keeps  the temperature difference between the clothes and the air just around them. This is how I would answer the question why wet clothes dry faster in windy air.

My questions:
1) Can we explain this by just using Bernoulli's principle?

2) Does it even apply in this situation if we want to determine the change in evaporation rates because of pressure decreases?

3) When there is wind, does it necessarily mean that the pressure is less than the no windy air case?

4) Would the change of evaporation rate due to pressure change be significant in this question?

Answer (score 3):

The local pressure could go either up or down when the wind blows, depending on the orientation of the object relative to the wind. But I suspect the total air pressure is irrelevant here, because its influence is negligible compared to the simple process of removal of air that is saturated with water vapour, and its replacement with drier air. After all, if some truly dry air came along, with no water content, then the partial pressure of water in that dry air would be not just small but zero! It seems to me that this is bound to be more significant than other factors.